# Javascript If condition to check a variable with empty object or not

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend, web-frontend

I have a variable var a = {};

```
if ( a !==null) {
// Entering here if var a has empty object but i don't want to enter.
}

if (a == null) {
// Want to enter into this condition if var a has empty object.
}
```

I have tried several ways to write this condition like giving a=={} but it still entering first condition. Could you please let me know the appropriate way to check that condition?

Comment: Thank you all for your valid responses. @Janaka dissanayake response came handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First option

```
var a = null;
```

Second option

```
if ( a !==null && JSON.stringify(a) !== '{}') {..}
```

Comment: const empty = {}
Object.keys(empty).length === 0 && empty.constructor === Object

Answer (score 2):

```js
function isEmptyObject(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).length == 0;
}

var a = {};

if (isEmptyObject(a)) {
  console.log('emptyOject')
}
```

Comment: What if a is null or undefined?  Should test for it in function.

Comment: @will Not in a function called `isEmptyObject`, if you change it to `isNullOrEmptyObject()` then maybe, but the OP 's example is about an empty object. `I have a variable var a = {};` In any case, that's trivial... I'm sure the OP can figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery does

```
function isEmptyObject(obj) {
    var name;
    for (name in obj) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: That's going to check inherited properties too. As long as the OP understands and chooses the one they want.

Answer (score 0):

In ECMA script 5

```
var objInTest = {};

function isEmpty(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
}
```

Pre ECMA script 5

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
    for(var prop in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```